Convertir String de base64 a Imagen
Necesito que en la Vista de mi programa java se muestren las imagenes que he insertado en la base de datos, ya pase la imagen a base64 y la puse en el insert correspondiente de la base de datos, luego en hice una funcion en el Gestor que meta esas imagenes en un arraylist, ahora en el Controlador tengo que pasar el string de base64 a imagen y no se como hacerlo. Esto es lo que llevo de momento en el controlador:
    public class ControladorGrupo {
        private ArrayList<Grupo> grupos = null;
        private GestorGrupo gestorGrupo= null;

        public void obtenerDatoGrupos () {
          grupos = new ArrayList<Grupo> ();
          gestorGrupo = new GestorGrupo ();
    
          grupos = gestorGrupo.obtener();
    }

    public void obtenerImagen (String base64String, BufferedImage imagen) {
    /*pasar de base64 a imagen*/
    
        try {
            byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);

            imagen = ImageIO.read(bis);

            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    
      }

     } 

Pero tambien me encontre con este otro cacho de codigo,no se como hacerlo funcionar
    public MainFrame(ArrayList<String> base64Strings) {
       setTitle("Imágenes desde Base64");
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setSize(400, 400);

       panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    // Itera sobre las cadenas Base64
    for (String base64String : base64Strings) {
    // Decodifica la cadena Base64 a bytes
    byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);

    // Crea un ImageIcon a partir de los bytes
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageBytes);

    // Crea un JLabel para mostrar la imagen
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(imageIcon);

    // Agrega el JLabel al panel
    panel.add(imageLabel);
    }

    // Agrega el panel al JFrame
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Ejemplo de ArrayList de códigos Base64
      ArrayList<String> base64Strings = new ArrayList<>();
    base64Strings.add("..."); // Agrega tus códigos Base64 aquí

    // Crea la ventana principal y muestra las imágenes
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame(base64Strings));
    }
    }

Me piden que no haya static, la imagen esta guardada en sql como un MEDIUMBLOB
